# How To covered space of hide control in cardview layout?

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, show-hide, cardview

All

I am working on card view in which I fetch data from SQLite.
on card view there is some controls are hide and some are show according to condition.

I need help how to covered hide space on screen after deployed.

Along with card view I have use Relative layout for set control as per design.

and Still I'm not using any code or condition for this, Any body have any idea or any suggestion for this?

Comment: I have some queries what do you mean bu covered hide space on screen and still im not using any code or condition for this

Comment: `CardView` is `FrameLayout`, can you show the layout which you are using? And tell us, what control you want to hide and cover its space, and then we will have a clear goal to help you.